# Notification doesn't close after clicked

Tags: android, notifications

I'm using a notification on my app to warn if a user haven't confirmed his attendance. But after confirming which is works since the database is changed the notification doesn't disappear. And I don't know if this had a connection but my screen keeps redirected back to the blank screen of the notification issuer's activity(because I don't declare any view at that activity since its only temporary visit) 
Here's My notification issuer's class code:

```
package travenz.tacos;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class JobNotif extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // Prepare intent which is triggered if the
    // notification is selected
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ScheduleList.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, ConfirmJobAttendance.class);
    intent2.putExtra("Tugas_ID", getIntent().getExtras().getString("Tugas_ID"));
    intent2.putExtra("Anggota_ID", getIntent().getExtras().getString("Anggota_ID"));
    PendingIntent pIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent2, 0);

    Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, RefuseJobAttendance.class);
    intent3.putExtra("Tugas_ID", getIntent().getExtras().getString("Tugas_ID"));
    intent3.putExtra("Anggota_ID", getIntent().getExtras().getString("Anggota_ID"));
    PendingIntent pIntent3 = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent3, 0);


    // Build notification
    // Actions are just fake
    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setContentTitle("You Haven't Confirmed to Attend a Job")
        .setContentText("Job Confirmation").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentIntent(pIntent)
        .addAction(R.drawable.confirm, "Confirm", pIntent2)
        .addAction(R.drawable.confused, "Not Now", pIntent)
        .addAction(R.drawable.no, "Not Attending", pIntent3)
        .build();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Hide the notification after its selected
    noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
 }

}
```

And Here's my notification receiver's class:

```
 package travenz.tacos;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;

 import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
 import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
 import org.json.JSONException;
 import org.json.JSONObject;

 import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.ProgressDialog;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.widget.Toast;

public class ConfirmJobAttendance extends Activity {
// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

// url to create new product
private static String UPDATE_JOB_ATTENDANCE_URL = "http://10.0.2.2/DatabaseCon/updateabsensitugas.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    new UpdateJob().execute();

    Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

public void onPause(){

    super.onPause();
    if(pDialog != null)
        pDialog.dismiss();
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Create new product
 * */
class UpdateJob extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ConfirmJobAttendance.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Confirming Attendance..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Creating product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Tugas_ID", getIntent().getExtras().getString("Tugas_ID")));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Anggota_ID", getIntent().getExtras().getString("Anggota_ID")));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Absen", "1"));


        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.setJSONFromUrl(UPDATE_JOB_ATTENDANCE_URL, params);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created job

            } else {

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(ConfirmJobAttendance.this, "You Have Updated Your Attendance", 1000);
        t.show();
        Exit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.confirm_job_attendance, menu);
    return true;
}

public void Exit(){
    Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using notification class then do this:

```
    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this);
         noti.flags = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
         noti.setContentTitle("You Haven't Confirmed to Attend a Job")
        .setContentText("Job Confirmation").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentIntent(pIntent)
        .addAction(R.drawable.confirm, "Confirm", pIntent2)
        .addAction(R.drawable.confused, "Not Now", pIntent)
        .addAction(R.drawable.no, "Not Attending", pIntent3);
    noti.build();
```

For those using notification builder: add this line:

```
notiBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
```

Comment: which builder()? I don't call .builder() at all.

Comment: I enterred the line but nothing different happens. The notification still won't dissapear

Comment: I get an error type mismatch: cannot convert from notification.builder to notification when adding your code.

Comment: found the problem it was your in code change it to Notification.Builder noti = new Notification.Builder(this);

Comment: I did that and now I get an error flags cannot be resolved or is not a field. Sorry to make you help me this far. But thanks and I hope we can clear this problem

Comment: remove flag try this notiBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

Comment: can you show me the full code of your suggestion? It could be that I'm doing any other code you're not mentioning wrong. Because this time I cant use notificationManager.notify because noti is a builder.